# pact-js Message Consumer Contract Example not working

Tags: node.js, pact, pact-node

I want to get started with Pact to enable Consumer Driven Contracts for our asynchronous message stream architecture.
Having read through most of the documentation and getting started guides by pact-foundation I tried to follow the example from https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/tree/master/examples/messages.
For now I only need the Consumer side of the Pact creation.

When I run

```
npm i
npm run test:consumer
```

I receive the following error on `debug` level:

```
[2020-04-02T09:30:19.822Z]  INFO: pact@9.2.2/15568 on MYPC: Verifying message
[2020-04-02T09:30:19.829Z]  INFO: pact-node@10.8.0/15568 on MYPC: Creating Message
[2020-04-02T09:30:19.839Z]  INFO: pact-node@10.8.0/15568 on MYPC: Creating message pact
[2020-04-02T09:30:19.849Z] DEBUG: pact-node@10.8.0/15568 on MYPC: Starting pact binary 'standalone\win32-1.82.1\pact\bin\pact-message.bat', with arguments ...
[2020-04-02T09:30:19.922Z] DEBUG: pact-node@10.8.0/15568 on MYPC: Created 'standalone\win32-1.82.1\pact\bin\pact-message.bat' process with PID: 20196
[2020-04-02T09:30:20.000Z] DEBUG: pact-node@10.8.0/15568 on MYPC:
    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Then I tracked it down to the call of
`.verify(synchronousBodyHandler(dogApiHandler))`
inside `message-consumer.spec.ts` which ultimately leads to the `class Spawn` that lives in `spawn.ts` within the pact-node repository of the pact-foundation.

For the example to properly call the Pact Creation logic I had to change the package.json file:

```
"test:consumer": "nyc --check-coverage --reporter=html --reporter=text-summary mocha consumer/*.spec.ts"
```

to

```
"test:consumer": "nyc --check-coverage --reporter=html --reporter=text-summary ts-mocha consumer/*.spec.ts"
```

I am running out of ideas, since my javascript/node.js/typescript skills are rather limited. Would appreciate any help.
Thanks and Cheers,
pypapo

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a bug with the example on Windows - could you please be so kind to raise this on the Pact JS repository? It should run on our Appveyor builds, but perhaps there is something we haven't considered.